# Re-earned all my tag badges at once

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Today I had virtually no activity on the site (other than visiting) and to my surprise I somehow just earned all of my tag badges simultaneously. As far as I am aware I already had all these badges before, earned at the appropriate time but they are now showing up as earned today.

You can see the effect [in my activity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/33707/sdjz?tab=activity). I also got the corresponding notifications:

[image]

I honestly don't think this has much of an impact other than the momentary confusion caused but I am still curious as to what happened, and whether this is worth reporting to the main meta.

Comment: My best guess is that it's an artefact of [recent work/poking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359857/681403) on the tag score bits.

Comment: I was re-awarded several of my own mainsite tag badges yesterday as well. (Not all, just some.)

Comment: Mainsite bug report: [Tag badges are re-awarded for some users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973) (which already links to this, including similar reports from other site metas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be resolved. Lots more details on what happened and why are available [on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360040/164200).

Answer (score 4):

### This seems to be a recurring event

It looks like whatever job is responsible for awarding (and unawarding) tag badges is acting up and reawarding badges to some users. Looking at the recent badges stream for both main and meta (main is presumably cut off due to other earned badges). No points for guessing how I noticed.

[image]

[image]

And [again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8x8V.png) and [again on meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms6un.png). I'll probably stop updating with new cases.